# MongoDB does not log anymore after I've removed the logfile

Tags: mongodb

I have had the mongod.log file of more than 10 GBs, so I deleted it. However, since then the file has not been recreated - did I mess it up by deleting the file? How to fix that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like mogodb does not like that, in fact many applications dont.
In the future you should either do it the correct way witch is to use the mongodb [logrotate directive](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/logRotate/)

OR, you can usually get away with truncating the logfile `sudo echo "" > /path/to/logfile.log` This empties the file content but leaves evrything else as is ([more on truncate](https://www.atatus.com/blog/empty-delete-or-rotate-log-files/#truncate-the-log-file)).

It should fix itself if you restart.